# Filter on XML child nodes

Tags: xml, powershell, msbuild

I'm trying to process `MSBuild` files to extract the filename in the `Include` attribute with the PowerShell snippet below.

```bsh
Get-ChildItem $xmlFile |
    ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.FullName; [xml](Get-Content $_) } |
    Where-Object {
        (($_.Project.ItemGroup -ne $null) -and
        ($_.Project.ItemGroup.ProjectFile -ne $null))
    } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Project.ItemGroup.ProjectFile } |
    Where-Object { ($_.Include -ne $null) } |
    ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
```

This works fine for XML that has the `ItemGroup` child element like this:

```xml
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="settings.props" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectFile Include="filename.proj"/>
```

But, when the XML hierarchy is different (no `ItemGroup` element) like below, the script fails with the error:

> The property 'ItemGroup' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.

Even the `ErrorAction` doesn't suppress the error output.

How can I check in the pipeline if the child element exist and skip files in which it doesn't? And also, why doesn't the `-ErrorAction` parameter work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to *load* the file using [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310), *cast* it to `xml` and try to select the node by yourself. Just use the [Select-XML](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135255) cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem $xmlFile | ForEach-Object {
    $node = Select-Xml -Path $_.FullName `
        -XPath '/n:Project/n:ItemGroup/n:ProjectFile/@Include' `
        -Namespace @{n = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'}

    if ($node)
    {
        $node.Node.Value
    }
}
```

It is using an `xpath` to select the `Include` attribute (and a `namespace`).

**Output**:

```
filename.proj
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Still am confused as why the Where-Object in my example doesn't.